# wp_footer hook running twice

Tags: plugins, widgets, footer

I have created a widget that have to run some code using the wp_footer hook as well. But if you extend the WP_Widget, the wp_footer runs twice! Has someone already past for the same issue?

Here is an example:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Test
Description: Test Plugin by Romulo De Lazzari
Version: 1.0
Author: Romulo De Lazzari
*/

new Test();

class Test extends WP_Widget{

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct('test-widget', 'Test Widget');      

        add_action('widgets_init', array($this, 'register_my_widget'));
        add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'do_something'));
    }

    public function register_my_widget(){
        return register_widget("Test");
    }

    public function do_something(){
        echo "<p>Hello! This is a test!</p>";
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance) {

    }

    public function form($instance){

    }

    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance){

    }

}
```

The method do_something() is running twice here, if I take off the "Widget part" it runs well. Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Romulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code doesn't look like it conforms to the current Widgets API. Perhaps your problem is related?

First potential issue: your class `test` should be `plugin-slug-test`, in order to avoid naming conflicts.

Second potential issue: the only functions inside of your WP_Widget extending class should be:

- function plugin-slug-test() {}
- function widget( $args, $instance ) {}
- function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {}
- function form( $instance ) {}

You need to move your `add_action()` calls *outside* of your Widget class.

Third potential issue: why do you declare all of your Widget class functions to be *public*?

Fourth potential issue: I don't think you need to declare `new Test();` for a Widget class.

Comment: Thanks, actually isn't the name conviction the problem, but the second tip have made me realise that I have to create two classes in the same file. One for the Widget (only with the widget, form and update methods) and another one for the wp_footer hook.